# form-login-config and ajax requests

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have setup my web.xml with a login page, however, I would like the server to return a 403 status for certain servlets that are used for async calls.

Servlets requiring authentication are all mapped as /restricted/*

I can only think of 2 options:

- mapping async servlets outside of "restricted" and checking for the roles in the servlets
- handling redirect to login page in servlets that forward to a page

Is there any other way I can do this and whilst keeping access control consistent throughout?